# how to do two complement multiplication and division of integers?

Tags: binary, division, multiplication, bit, twos-complement

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899401/binary-multiplication-2s-complement) on binary multiplication using two complement. but it is not very clear to me. Even I have difficulty understanding the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Multiplication) article on this. I want to know how to go about calculating multiplications of negative numbers:

```
eg: -1 with -7 should give 7.
A 4-bit, 2's complement of -1 is : 1111
A 4-bit, 2's complement of -7 is : 1001
```

some step-wise way of calculating the multiplication will be helpful. No article I came across talks about division. How to approach this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

step 1: `sign extend` both integers to twice as many bits. This is safe to do, though may not always be necessary.

```
for 4-bit --> 1111, you would extend as 1111 1111
for 4-bit --> 0111,you would extend as 0000 0111
```

step 2: do elementary multiplication

sep 3: take the correct number of result bits from the least significant portion of the result.

eg: after multiplication, you end up with something such as `0010011110` take the last 8 bits i.e `10011110`

Let me illustrate with the example you provided: `-1 X -7` in 4-bit representation

```
         1111 1111        -1
       x 1111 1001     x  -7
      ----------------    ------
          11111111         7
         00000000
        00000000
       11111111
      11111111
     11111111
    11111111
   11111111
   ----------------
1  00000000111       --->  7 (notice the Most significant bit is zer``o)
      --------  (last 8-bits needed)
```

you could get more details [here](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkhill/cs354/Fall2008/beyond354/int.mult.html);

for division: convert to positive and after the calculation adjust the sign. I will leave this as exercise but you could refer this [page](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Erajeev/cs3810/slides/3810-08.pdf).

Comment: what if I am allowed with only 4-bit representation, and cannot extend to 8-bit

Comment: @eagertoLearn: the doubling bits is for calculation purposes, it is not necessary in the final result. however, note that  the maximum the 4-bit bit can hold is is 2^4-1 which is 15

Comment: Multiplication does not require extension to double width. Just do the math mod 16.

Comment: @RaymondChen: what do you mean by math mod 16? can you elaborate please?

Comment: @user1988876 although a 4 bit **unsigned** value allows up to 15, we're working with signed values, which means 4 bits can only get us to 7.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's see if I can make this simple enough for you.

Two's complement:
IFF (If and only if) you have a negative number, first put it into the positive form. For sake of simplicity, all numbers will be 6 bit. The limit of the bits will limit how big your numbers can go. Besides that, what the size is doesn't matter.

Some numbers converted to their positive binary form
-7: 000111
16: 010000
-22: 010110
1: 000001

Now for -7  and -23 ONLY we'll do two's complement on. So we flip the bits (1 -> 0 && 0 -> 1) and then add one.

```
 000111
 Goes to the complement + 1
 111000
 +    1
=111001
```

And for 22

```
 010110
 Goes to the complement + 1
 101001
+     1
=101010
```

Then you just add them together like you would any other number.

And it looks like somebody else already covered the multiplication part, so I won't bother repeating that.

Comment: No problem. Is that clear enough? And between the two of us, did we miss any part of your question?